# how to send multiple parameter during uploading image using jquery and IHttpHandler in c#

Tags: c#, jquery

i am uploading image using jquery and http handler in c#...i want to send muple valriable in handler with file uploading data..My code is given below..here is my jquery code...

```
var filename = document.getElementById("<%=fileuploadimages.ClientID %>");
           var files = fileUpload.files;
                var test = new FormData();
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    test.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: "UploadHandler.ashx",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: test,

                    // dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.statusText);
                    }
                });
```

here is my handler code for uploading image

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                    string fname;
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                    {
                        string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                        fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fname = file.FileName;
                    }
                    fname = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/UserImage/"), fname);
                    file.SaveAs(fname);
                }
            }
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("File Uploaded Successfully!");
        }


        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

every thing is working fine my problem is that i want to send an another variable with test..like var a="xxx"..i want to send the a variable also with test..how to do this???can any one help me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the method "append" to add more items to FormData object, something like this:

Javascript:

`var test = new FormData();
test.append("txtHome",$("#txtHome").val()); //Name and value`

In your handler:

`context.Request.Form["txtHome"]; //Get the value with the name of variable`